# Heyzap Ads Ad is not ready

Tags: android, heyzap, rewardedvideoad

Hi I am using Hey zap for show Rewarded Video Ads in android. I used this [documentation](https://developers.heyzap.com/docs/android_sdk_setup_and_requirements) . But I tried to show ads in application its show in the screen this `Ad is not ready, as zone vzd448459637794d338c is V4VC enabled and must be played using an AdColonyV4VCAd object`" After 5 minutes it show still this one .How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I work on Heyzap's Android SDK.

The zone mentioned in that error message is set as the "Interstitial Zone ID" in our dashboard. If you don't intend to use interstitial ads, just remove that zone id entirely, and that may solve your problem.

It's also possible that AdColony isn't filling your rewarded video zone for some unrelated reason. Could you send us a copy of your APK? I could check it out and see if they fill for me, or if I see any other relevant error messages.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks and I solved when I used AdColony this problem is come up but AdMob is working without problem.